# Vtk set colors at once without loop

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5, vtk

I try to set colors to points but without loop `InsertNextTuple3()`.
The ndarray `np_rgb_array` is nx3 size.

```
def set_threshold(self, new_value):

    np_rgb_array = (np.ones((self.points.shape))*new_value).astype(int)

    rgb2 = npsup.numpy_to_vtk(np_rgb_array ,deep=1)
    rgb2.SetName("Colors")

    self.vtk_vertex.GetPointData().SetScalars(rgb2)
    self.mapper.SetInputData(self.vtk_vertex)
    self.mapper.Modified()
    self.actor.GetProperty().Modified()
    self.render_window.Render()
```

This function is invoked by slider of pyqt and the range is 0-255 `new_value`,
when I run and change the slider first time the color of all points change to blue and then nothing changes... I have this function working but with loop and `InsertNextTuple3`

Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order it to work `rgb2` was need to be Unsigned char type vtk array. So I basicly created new array `rgb3` that have proper type and did `.ShallowCopy()` the data from `rgb2` which is double type array.

```
def set_threshold(self, new_value):

    rgb3 = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
    rgb3.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
    rgb3.SetName("Colors")

    test = np.ones((self.points.shape))*new_value
    vtk_test = npsup.numpy_to_vtk(test,deep=1)
    vtk_test.SetName("Colors")

    rgb3.ShallowCopy(vtk_test)
    self.vtk_vertex.GetPointData().SetScalars(rgb3)

    self.mapper.SetInputData(self.vtk_vertex)
    self.mapper.Modified()
    self.actor.GetProperty().Modified()
    self.render_window.Render()
```

Also rerendering works much faster!